# How to import a library from github?

Tags: android, android-library, android-studio-import

I don't understand how to add a library in my new project.

https://github.com/txusballesteros/bubbles-for-android

I saw similar posts but I don't get the library in my project.

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

And when I add the library can I change the original source code and can I use it because I read about the same License ?

Please help me, I was trying many methods and I failed.

Comment: I add this error  code because they dont let me to post this quastion **

Comment: it is already given in your link. Add that dependency in your buil.gradle file and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate your build.gradle file:

1. Go to `android view` (easiest this way)
2. Locate `Gradle Scripts` folder:

[image]

3. Locate your correct build.gradle file (watch it, there are 2 of those who look similar):

[image]

4. Add the this statement (`compile 'com.txusballesteros:bubbles:1.2.1'`) according to picture:

[image]

5. Good to go

Comment: I understand that but how can I change somthing from the library?

Answer (score 1):

Add the library dependency in your app level build.gradle file(not project level). you don't need to download any library file just add this dependency and sync the project

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.txusballesteros:bubbles:1.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your Build.Gradle under dependency block and then sync. project. Now you can use that library methods in your code.

```
compile 'com.txusballesteros:bubbles:1.2.1'
```